# No se sustituyen las variables Less al compilar y produce error

Tags: css, mvc, variables, less

Estoy usando por primera vez less y estoy teniendo algunos problemas. Es un proyecto de **MVC** y estoy utilizando **dotless** y *System.Web.Optimization.Less*.

He registrado un bundle para incluir todos mis ficheros less y devolver al navegador un único fichero minimizado.

```
         bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Less").Include(
                 "~/Styles/Layout/Colores.less", 
                 "~/Styles/Layout/Global.less"));
```

Como se puede observar, estoy incluyendo un fichero de colores que contiene las variables que los definen, para poder utilizarlas luego en el resto de ficheros less del proyecto. También incluyo un fichero para definir el estilo global de la aplicación que utiliza estas variables..

Pero cuando voy con el navegador a la página, el fichero less generado contiene el siguiente error:

```
    /* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
      (54,12): run-time error CSS1036: Expected expression, found '@colorBlanco'
      (83,15): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found ';'
    */
```

Mi fichero Color.less tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
    @colorGris:         #808080;
    @colorBlanco:       #FFFFFF;


    /*Bordes*/
    @colorBordeInput:       #b1b1b1;
    @colorBordeContainer:   #E9EAEC;


    /*Sombras*/
    @colorSombraInput:      #a5a5a5;
    @colorSombraFocusInput: #81005D;



    /*******************
      ****  Layout ****
     *******************/
        /* userDataLine */
        @colorNombreUsuario: #700056;
```

Cual es el problema? Si veo el fichero global.css file que es generado automáticamente en Visual Studio si veo que se ha cambiado la variable por su valor correspondiente, por ejemplo:

```
#whereIAm #titleAndPath span {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El `StyleBundle` realiza la minificación de los archivos css pero no compila los archivos less.

Si ya estás generando, como comentas, los archivos css desde el propio entorno de desarrollo son éstos los que deberías añadir al bundle.

Comment: Claro, la compilación del fichero less la realiza dotless cuando detecta que el navegador realiza una petición de un fichero.less. Una opción es lo que comentas, pero prefiero intentar primero incluyendo el fichero less. En internet hay guias donde incluyen en el StyleBundle los ficheros less, pero solo incluyen uno, por lo que no tienen problemas de dependencias... Gracias por la respuesta, si me rindo lo intentaré así.

Comment: Pero no entiendo dónde estás realizando la compilación de los less. El StyleBundle va a realizar una minificación de los archivos less como si fueran archivos css (lo cual podría funcionar aunque habría que buscar alguna solución para los @import). Y tal y como lo tienes el navegador acabará pidiendo un archivo ".../Content/Less?v=xxxxxx". ¿Dónde exactamente realizas la compilación con dotless?

Comment: La compilación la realiza automáticamente dotless, pues en el webconfig se incluye una regla que avisa al servidor de que cuando se requieran ficheros less se deben procesar por dotless: <system.webserver><handlers><add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" /></handlers></system.webserver>

Comment: Básicamente he seguido lo explicado en esta guia, pues es la primera vez que utilizo less... http://www.brendanforster.com/blog/yet-another-implement-less-in-aspnetmvc-post.html

Comment: Pero según ese post el handler del web.config lo utiliza para cuando el bundling no está activo (generalmente en modo debug). Cuando el bundling está activo es la propia clase que genera el bundle la que se encarga de realizar la compilación. En el post utiliza una clase `LessBundle` cuyo código (según pone en el post) tomó de https://gist.github.com/benfoster/3924025

Answer (score 0):

Ok, buscando en el sitio web de ASP.NET he encontrado la respuesta. Efectivamente, el problema era que no se estaba realizando la compilación previa. Asumí que se hacía automáticamente, pero parece que hay que crear una clase que implemente IBundleTransform y llamar explícitamente para que se realice la compilación.

Viene muy bien explicado en este enlace: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Gracias Asier, tu respuesta me ha puesto en el camino adecuado para terminar encontrando la solución!!!

Comment: Eso es. La clase `StyleBundle` únicamente aplica la transformación `CssMinify` necesitabas realizar previamente otra: la compilación de less. Se puede hacer dentro de tu propia clase `Bundle` (como en el primer post que tomabas como guía) o añadiendo transformaciones al `Bundle` (como en el enlace que pones en tu respuesta)